# Code breaks when using later version of PHP

Tags: php, forms, character-encoding

I have the following code which breaks when I upgrade from PHP v5.2.17 --> v5.3.5 and I can't figure out what it is. Does anyone have a clue as to what could be wrong? Thanks.

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');

$goto = $_POST['location'];

function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }
    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    return $clean;
}
?>
```

---

There are no errors of any sort and I looked over my cms logs and there is nothing unusual. I did setup a simple test and here is what happens:

```
<?php
$goto = $_POST['location']; 
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') { 
  if( !empty($replace) ) { 
    $str = str_replace((array) $replace, ' ', $str); 
  } 
  $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
  $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean); 
  $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-')); 
  $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean); 
  return $clean; 
}
?>
```

Output is: `<?echo toAscii($goto);?>`
Output is: `<?echo $goto;?>`

When I output the raw form data it works great and when I output the `toAscii($goto)` data it returns nothing.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Do you get an useful error messages? Stack trace?

Comment: Also, interestingly enough I use this exact code in a PHP 5.3 app of my own. It works fine. Perhaps you don't have the iconv extension installed?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I get no errors. I use this code on a "jump" page which processes a simple form, cleans the form input to be url friendly and adds the output to another url which it redirects to.

Comment: So what should happen, I would input text into the form on page 1 and submit the form, on page 2, this php code above would process the form, strip out the bad characters and put the result into a url string which redirects me to page 3.

Comment: <darn return key> This method works fine in php v5.2.17 but always kicks me back to page 1 in php v5.3.5 with no error or any other information.

Comment: @mike swift, @nullref, @peeter I've given some additional info on the problem in other comments on this page. I still haven't resolved this problem and would really be grateful for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have not added an error message to your question, but as the code uses only one non-standard function, namely `iconv`, it's hightly likely that you haven't installed/enabled the [iconv extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php).

To solve the problem, enable the needed extension and the code should work as you know it from the other PHP configuration.

If the extension is available and enabled (which should be the case with PHP 5.3) from the top of my head, then you should add more information to your question what's actually breaking. What is not working as intended?

---

To troubleshoot, above your code place:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will take care that errors and warnings are directly visible.

---

To continue trouble shooting, let's take care inside the routine that is not properly working. Exemplary I've added a check for the return value of `iconv`, the same can be applied on any kind of variable (testing if a variable contains what should be expected) or function return values:

```
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') { 
  if( !empty($replace) ) { 
    # NOTE: no need to cast to array. It's either array or string, both work
    $str = str_replace($replace, ' ', $str);
  }
  # NOTE: inconv will return FALSE on error. Checking this now.
  $result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
  if (FALSE === $result) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Iconv failed on "%s".', $str));
  } else {
    $clean = $result;
  }

  $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
  $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-')); 
  $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean); 
  return $clean; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have pretty lightweight php skills and I don't know how to install a iconv extension to try out your suggestion. I'm using a MAMP server (essentially LAMP on a Mac). How would I go about adding this extension?

Comment: First check if it's already available: create a single .php file with the code `<?php phpinfo(); ` in there. Request that file with your browser and it will list all installed and enabled extensions. Check if iconv is part of the list or not.

Comment: And what kind of error are you getting? Just a white page an no error at all?

Comment: hakre - no error just get bumped back to the first page where the form is submitted. This is probably a function of my CMS.

Comment: So what SHOULD happen, I would input text into the form on page 1 and submit the form, on page 2, this php code above would process the form, strip out the bad characters and put the result into a url string which redirects me to page 3.

Comment: @hakre Here is the relevant info from my phpinfo report: iconv support enabled
iconv implementation libiconv
iconv library version 1.13

Comment: sounds like you have iconv installed. Can you check your PHP error logs? or any logs your CMS uses?

Comment: @mikeswift nope there are no errors of any sort and I looked over my cms logs and there is nothing unusual. I did setup a simple test and here is what happens:

Comment: <?php
$goto = $_POST['location'];
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
 if( !empty($replace) ) {
 $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
 }
 $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
 $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
 $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
 $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
 return $clean;
}?>
Output is: <?echo toAscii($goto);?><br>
Output is: <?echo $goto;?>  When I output the raw form data it works great and when I output the toAscii($goto) data it returns nothing.

Comment: @Peeter: I've added some code you should place above your code to enable error reporting and display for all kind of errors. Probably a regular expression fails. You should further check if one of the function returns `FALSE` (`=== FALSE`) because that would look like an empty string and would pass merely unnoticed with your current code.

Comment: @mikeswift When I placed the error reporting code this is the result: Fatal error: Call to undefined function init_set() in /Applications/MAMP/iSawYou/webapp/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code on line 6

Comment: @mikeswift Here is the cms code which the above error points to:  /**
  * eval() 
  *
  * Evaluates a string as PHP
  *
  * @access public
  * @param string
  * @return mixed
  */ 
 function evaluate($str)
 { 
  return eval('?'.'>'.$str.'<?php ');  
 }
 
 // --------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @mikeswift That seemed to work but now I get absolutely no errors at all. To be sure here is the code again: <?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$goto = $_POST['location'];

function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
 if( !empty($replace) ) {
  $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
 }
 $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
 $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
 $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
 $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
 return $clean;
}
?>

Comment: Okay, next part is then to look which part of the routine fails. That means each time you call a function in there, properly check the return value. Many of them return `FALSE` on error.

Comment: @hakre Sounds good but I have no idea how to implement what you suggest. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @hakre I set-up the test for all the return values as you suggested and there was no error or any type of indication that something is wrong, it's simply that it returns nothing. What else can I do? This is an important part of my site and if I can't get this to work with my server software then I'm hosed. ;-(